# MAPI Properties to check/uncheck Secuity properties

Tags: outlook, mapi, outlook-2016

In Outlook 2016 (Outlook 2016 MSO 16.0.4266.1001 64 bit) , when S/Mime user accepts a calendar invitation sent by a non s-mime user, following error is displayed.

"Microsoft Outlook cannot sign or encrypt this message because there are no certificates which can be used to send from the email address  . Either get a new digital ID to use with this account, or use the accounts button to send the message using an account that you have certificates for."

This error is not seen with Outlook 2013.

These 3 security properties are checked on opening the event (which are unchecked in Outlook 2013)

- Encrypt message contents and attachments.
- Add digital signature to outgoing messages.
- Request S/Mime receipt for this message.

What mapi properties are used to check/uncheck these security properties?